# Radius of convergence of the power series $\sum_n a_n x^n$ where $a_n={{\sin (n!)}\over {n!}}$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, proof-writing, power-series

> Find the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$ where $a_n={{\sin (n!)}\over {n!}}.$

Now using the ratio test $$R=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left|{{a_n}\over {a_{n+1}}}\right|\\=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left|n\cdot{\sin(n!)\over \sin((n+1)!)}\right|$$ Now, $n\rightarrow \infty$ but the limit of ${\sin(n!)\over \sin((n+1)!)}$ is not known to me. If in degrees, I could say it converges to $1$ as $360$ devides every integer of form $n!,\forall n\ge 360.$  and the $R$ would be $\infty.$ But as the questions says, I have to find this in **radians.**  The options are $1.R\ge 1, 2.R\ge 2\pi, R\le 4\pi , R\ge \pi.$ Please help. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the root test;
since
$|\sin(n!)| < 1$
and
$n!^{1/n} \to n/e$,
$|{{\sin (n!)}\over {n!}}|^{1/n}
<\frac{1}{n/e}
\to 0
$
so the series converges
everywhere.

Comment: to me, it is not obvious that $n!^{1/n} \to n/e $?

Comment: Is this based on Stirling's approximation?

Comment: Ridiculous down-vote. +1 Indeed this uses Stirling's approximation.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Compare it to Taylor's series of $e^x$ function , and that series converges everywhere.